# OS-X localhost resolving strangely

Tags: macos, networking, osx-yosemite

The issue I'm about to describe I see only when I run some Java unit tests. However, I'm pretty sure that the cause is OS-X configuration, not Java, so I'm posting to superuser not StackOverflow.

We have a Java unit test that starts up an embedded server and then makes requests against in at `http://localhost:9324`. These tests used to pass before I upgraded to Yosemite, now they fail. Specific symptoms and things I've tried:

*Resolving to AWDL interface*

I looked at netstat to see what was hitting port 9324. Found this:

```
localhost:platform oliver$ netstat -tn | grep 9324
tcp6       0      0  fe80::b8d2:8eff:.50602 fe80::b8d2:8eff:.9324  SYN_SENT
```

so for some reason localhost was resolving to an IPV6 address and `ifconfig` shows it's the address of `awdl0`. A little Googling shows that's the interface Apple uses for peer-to-peer sharing. Note that `nslookup localhost`, `dig localhost` and `dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost` all return `127.0.0.1` as expected. So, somehow the Java code is doing the name resolution differently or something (so yes, maybe this is a Java question)???

*Resolving to External Address*

Turning off the AWDL interface via `sudo ifconfig awdl0 down` caused the code to stop hanging and netstat to report basically correct looking info:

```
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.124.52137    192.168.0.124.9324     SYN_SENT   
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9324         127.0.0.1.52135        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.52135        127.0.0.1.9324         ESTABLISHED
```

but note that for some reason, local code using a `localhost` address is hitting `192.168.0.124`, my **external** ip address and that code is stuck in `SYN_SENT` and will hang and never get a response. Note that this is not due to firewall settings as I disabled the firewall completely for this test.

*Connection Refused*

Despite the strange use of the external address, there are correct looking connections that appear to use the loopback, but they get `ConnectionRefused` errors from Java. However, `curl http://localhost:9324` connects successfully and gets a response.

*Question*

I'm pretty stumped. This could be a Java issue, but I suspect my OS-X network setup is borked somehow.

Oh, here's my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 10.1.10.1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::2
```

My /private/etc/resolv.conf is identical.

/etc/hosts is:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

and here's the output if `ifconfig -a`:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 3c:15:c2:da:29:0c 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:04:0f:34:70 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:04:0f:34:71 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0e:15:c2:da:29:0c 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8902<BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1452
    ether ba:d2:8e:05:03:6c 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 3e:15:c2:ad:9e:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=23<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4>
    ether 00:24:9b:0f:3c:02 
    inet6 fe80::224:9bff:fe0f:3c02%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    inet 192.168.0.50 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 2601:1c0:c901:980e:224:9bff:fe0f:3c02 prefixlen 64 autoconf 
    inet6 2601:1c0:c901:980e:4041:88e9:46e8:a893 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
    status: active
```

Comment: "My /private/etc/resolv.conf is identical." -> that's because /etc is a symlink to /private/etc. :)

Comment: I was facing the same problem. This [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698914/5021323) for me

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the post-IPv4 world. When you use an utility like nslookup or dig, the default is to return an "A" record. However, with modern IPv6 enabled operating systems and applications, they will typically check for an "AAAA" record first to see if the resource is available over IPv6 before resorting to an IPv4 resource.

So what is happening is that you have both an IPv4 entry and an IPv6 entry for *localhost* on your system and it will almost always prefer IPv6.

So, what can you do about this? Well, you have several options. You could remove the IPv6 entry for *localhost* or disable IPv6 entirely, however this is a less than ideal solution and is in effect "looking backward" rather than moving forward.

Instead, you should probably make sure that your service is configured to run on IPv6 in addition to IPv4.  You may also have to make some adjustments in your IPv6 firewall rules to allow the service. This prepares you for the future when IPv6 displaces IPv4 as the mainstream protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't think what you're describing is the issue. First, the initial v6 address I was seeing was for awdl0, not the loopback which is wrong. Second, after shutting down awdl0 you can see from netstat and such that everything is running over IPv4, not v6. Finally, from you /etc/resolve.conf you can see that I do have correct v6 localhost entries.

Comment: While *localhost* often does reference a loopback interface, there is no reason it cannot reference any other interface.  Does your loopback interface have IPv6 configured (could you edit your question to provide the output from *ifconfig*)? If not, another interface will be used for IPv6 if available. To your second point, this is more proof that it is trying to use IPv6 before IPv4. And for your final point, resolve.conf has nothing to do with your *localhost* entries, those are your DNS entries. Could you provide the contents of your */etc/hosts* file?

Comment: added /etc/hosts and ifconfig output to question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting `discoveryd` or flushing its cache, or reverting to mDNSResponder (the pre-Yosemite DNS resolver).

Here's how to flush the `discoveryd` cache:

> sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache

Reverting to mDNSResponder is described here:

> [Ars Technica OS X discoveryd revert](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The discoveryutil mdnsfluchcache trick did not solve the problem. I haven't yet tried the 2nd fix; it seems risky and will take some time. I will try it eventually if I can't find anything else that works.